# Create Json-string with Jackson using loops

Tags: java, json, jackson

I have three `String[][]` arrays that can be of different lengths. The second length is always fixed, and has length of `6`, but the first length can differ between `0` and `6`.

I want to create a Json-string containing the data of all of these `String` arrays. As of now it's hard coded, but i realize I'll get in to trouble once the lengths isn't fixed anymore...

```
travelgl1.put("Duration", str1[0][0]);
travelgl1.put("Walking time", str1[0][1]);
travelgl1.put("Direction", str1[0][2]);
travelgl1.put("Departure", str1[0][3]);
travelgl1.put("Arrival", str1[0][4]);
travelgl1.put("End station", str1[0][5]);
```

So basically I want a dynamic loop that loops through the `String` arrays and adds all the data in that array.

Is there any easy way to do this? I want all three json objects (from the three `String` arrays) to be compiled in to one big json string in the end.

I want the end result to look like this:

> [ { "String array 1" : [ { "Duration" : "33", "Walking time" : "8", "Direction" : "Åkeshov", "Departure" : "09:39", "Arrival" : "10:43", "End station" : "Sollentuna" }, { "Duration" : "37", "Walking time" : "8", "Direction" : "Alvik", "Departure" : "09:43", "Arrival" : "10:51", "End station" : "Sollentuna" }, { "Duration" : "34", "Walking time" : "8", "Direction" : "Alvik", "Departure" : "09:53", "Arrival" : "10:58", "End station" : "Sollentuna" }, { "Duration" : "36", "Walking time" : "8", "Direction" : "Åkeshov", "Departure" : "09:59", "Arrival" : "11:06", "End station" : "Sollentuna" }, { "Duration" : "33", "Walking time" : "8", "Direction" : "Åkeshov", "Departure" : "10:09", "Arrival" : "11:13" } ] }, 
>   { "String array 2" : [ { "Duration" : "54", "Walking time" : "13", "Direction" : "Farsta strand", "Departure" : "09:43", "Arrival" : "11:13", "End station" : "Sollentuna" }, { "Duration" : "47", "Walking time" : "13", "Direction" : "Gullmarsplan", "Departure" : "09:50", "Arrival" : "11:13", "End station" : "Sollentuna" }, { "Duration" : "45", "Walking time" : "13", "Direction" : "Gullmarsplan", "Departure" : "10:00", "Arrival" : "11:21", "End station" : "Sollentuna" }, { "Duration" : "42", "Walking time" : "13", "Direction" : "Gullmarsplan", "Departure" : "10:10", "Arrival" : "11:28", "End station" : "Sollentuna" }, { "Duration" : "45", "Walking time" : "13", "Direction" : "Gullmarsplan", "Departure" : "09:30", "Arrival" : "10:51", "End station" : "Sollentuna" } ] }, 
>   { "String array 3" : [ { "Duration" : "31", "Walking time" : "12", "Direction" : "Hässelby strand", "Departure" : "09:45", "Arrival" : "10:51", "End station" : "Sollentuna" }, { "Duration" : "31", "Walking time" : "12", "Direction" : "Alvik", "Departure" : "09:52", "Arrival" : "10:58", "End station" : "Sollentuna" }, { "Duration" : "33", "Walking time" : "12", "Direction" : "Åkeshov", "Departure" : "09:58", "Arrival" : "11:06", "End station" : "Sollentuna" }, { "Duration" : "30", "Walking time" : "12", "Direction" : "Åkeshov", "Departure" : "10:08", "Arrival" : "11:13", "End station" : "Sollentuna" }, { "Duration" : "31", "Walking time" : "12", "Direction" : "Hässelby strand", "Departure" : "10:15", "Arrival" : "11:21", "End station" : "Sollentuna" } ] } ]

So, what I really want is a dynamic way of creating a Json string depending on the length of the string array.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

please take the reference to the below code.

```
public List<Map<String, String>> myfunction(String str1[][]) {
    List<Map<String, String>> travelgl1 = new ArrayList<Map<String, String>>();
    for (int i = 0; i < str1.length; i++) {
        Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
        for (int j = 0; j < 6; j++) {
            if (j == 0)
                map.put("Duration", str1[i][j]);
            else if (j == 1)
                map.put("Walking time", str1[i][j]);
            else if (j == 2)
                map.put("Direction", str1[i][j]);
            else if (j == 3)
                map.put("Departure", str1[i][j]);
            else if (j == 4)
                map.put("Arrival", str1[i][j]);
            else if (j == 5)
                map.put("End station", str1[i][j]);
        }
        travelgl1.add(map);
    }
    return travelgl1;
}
```